# Clearing ttl from an object in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to clear a TTL from a document once it's set?  I've tried doing an update operation with the following scripts, which don't seem to do anything:

```
"ctx._ttl = null"
"ctx.remove('_ttl')"
```

Whereas I'm able to successfully set the ttl via:

```
"ctx._ttl = 60000"
```

I could deal with this by setting an extremely high ttl, but I'd rather clear it completely to avoid any performance overhead (and plus what if my code is still running in a million years, you never know).

My use case is I'm tracking web site visitors; some large percentage of them disappear and never return, in which case I'd like to clear their data after a month, but a few sign up and become permanent visitors, in which case I'd like their data not to expire.